# Qual a diferença entre NULL e null?

Tags: php, null

Existe alguma diferença entre o `NULL` (escrito em maiúsculo) e `null` (escrito em minúsculo) no PHP?

Eu sei que consigo usar os dois tipos, mas existe alguma regra de nomenclatura dessas palavras?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em **linhas gerais**, não existem diferenças. O *NULL* é *case insensitive* - não sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas. Na própria [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) é dito isso:

> Existe apenas um valor de tipo nulo, e essa é a constante **case insensitive** NULL.

O mesmo vale para o *TRUE* e *FALSE*. Como dito também na [documentação](http://php.net/language.types.boolean), ambos são *case insensitive*:

> Para especificar um booleano literal, utilize as constantes TRUE ou FALSE. **Ambas são case insensitive**.

Então você pode usar qual é mais conveniente, ou a que você tem mais familiaridade.

---

As [PSR's](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#25-keywords-and-truefalsenull) comentam sobre isso. Apesar de serem apenas um guia de estilo e não regras para serem impostas, elas recomendam que:

> As palavras chave do PHP devem estar em **minúsculas**. As constantes do PHP *true*, *false* e *null* devem estar escritas em **minúsculas**.

Também temos uma pergunta respondida sobre isso no nosso [Grande Irmão SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8864).